# Paypal not adding shipping value to total price

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

I'm implementing an ecommerce application and one way of paying is with paypal and there's shipping values for when total is under a certain value. When this happen I put in my paypal payment button an shipping value wich is like this:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="5" />
```

But when I test it with sandbox the shipping value is not added to the total price. I check the request and paypal receives my shipping value. Any idea what's wrong?

Could it be because I'm testing in sandbox? Maybe some bug with the sandbox and shipping values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question, it's not "shipping" but "shipping_1". So it would be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="5" />
```

Hope it helps someone :)